# Hadoop: Can we have different block sizes for different datasets?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hiveql, partition

Can we have different block sizes for different types of datasets?
Suppose I have two tables, one contains data of 10TB while another just contains data of 10GB. 
 Can I have different block sizes for the two of them, like 256MB for the former and 64MB for the latter, so as to increase my performance.

If yes, then please suggest a way to implement this. Also, can this be reduced to partition level? Where one partition has more data and the other has less and so I can have more block size for the bigger one?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Why you think the performance is increased? It more depends on number of nodes in your cluster than on block size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HIVE/ORC to store datasets, you can override the block size in the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycol string,..)
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("hive.exec.orc.default.block.size"="67108864");
```

For partitions, I don't see any solution.